# Изменять свойства обьекта без IBOutlet. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiviewcontroller

У меня в сториборде  на ViewController'е есть несколько лейблов у которых нет связи с классом этого сториборда. Outlet i Action не подключены.

*Как я могу поменять цвет заднего фона для всех лейблов на экране без подключений (Outlet i Action) ?*

Я думал можно использовать  какой то extension для класса, что то типа этого, но оно не работает.

```
 extension MyViewController {
    
        func changeBG(_ sender:UIButton) {
        sender.backgroundCOlor = .white
          }
        }
        
        class MyViewController:UIViewCоntroller {
        
          override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
        changeBG(UIButton) //-> Error
        //Cannot convert value of type 'UILabel.Type' to expected argument type 'UILabel'   
  }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы проделывать такое, Вам нужно создавать элементы интерфейса кодом, а не на сториборде.
Например, создание лейбла:

```
  private let yourLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "Привет!"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    return label
  }()
```

Далее в тексте программы, добавив этот лейбл на свою вьюшку и установив в коде констрейнты, вы можете менять свойства лейбла (или сразу нескольких) обращаясь к нему через обычный точечный синтаксис. Например, сделать невидимым:

```
yourLabel.isHidden = true
```

или изменить текст:

```
yourLabel.text = "Новый текст"
```

По сути, ваш пример ориентирован на тоже самое (на элементы, созданные кодом), только там как-то, мне кажется, не очень верно написано.

Comment: Элементы нужно было добавить именно в сториборде, а менять задний фон уже кодом. Я нашел решение, прикрепил ниже. Спасибо за ваш ответ )

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо! Буду знать :)

Answer (score 1):

Я прохожу циклом по всем `view` что есть на `darkView`. И если `view` типа `UILabel`, то задаю цвет заднего фона.

```
for view in self.darkView.subviews as [UILabel] {
    if let label = view as? UILabel {
        label.backgroundColor =  UIColor.black
    }
}
```